# Nginx differentiate between domain and sub-domain

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I have mydomain.com (192.168.1.10)
I have two other servers 192.168.1.11 and 192.168.1.12

Now I want *.mydomain.com to point to 192.168.1.11 and mydomain.com to point to 192.168.1.12

I have tried many examples with no luck.

Anyone knows how to achieve this??

Is there anything similar to:

```
location *.mydomain {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need location directive for subdomains, just setup separate servers with regexp notation:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  ...
}

server {
  server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.example\.com$;
  #you can use $subdomain in configuration
  #root /var/www/example.com/$subdomain;
  ...
}
```

Then you can set any backend (upstream) or proxy settings for those servers.